# Geolocation is already allowed on iOS Safari 16 but navigator permissions still says "prompt"

Tags: javascript, geolocation, mobile-safari

I'm using geolocation for detecting location...

```js
if ("permissions" in navigator) {
  navigator.permissions.query({ name:'geolocation' }).then((result) => {
    if (result.state === 'granted') {
      console.log("granted")
    } else if(result.state === 'denied'){
      console.log("denial")
    } else {
      console.log("prompt")
    }
  });
}
```

In Android web browser everything is okay but in iOS web browser, even if I already allowed location, the output is always "prompt", even if I refresh many times.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some google console extension involved? Does iPhone need to use google paid service (google console)? The problem is only in iPhone/iOS (even on Safari 16+), other devices are okay. Feature should be supported in iOS 16+.

Answer (score 2):

Safari is strict with privacy, if you look at the settings for location sharing in iOs under: `Settings` - `Privacy & Security` - `Location Services` - `Safari Websites`

you'll see even if you enable them **while using the app** the explanation text states:

```
App explanation: "Websites you visit may request your location"
```

Meaning that even with this access granted, sites must still prompt the user to ask for permission, regardless of the fact that you have granted it in the settings. In other words, you are giving Safari permission to access your location, not the websites you visit in Safari.

In your case, you can trigger the prompt by requesting the user's location with the `getCurrentPosition` method:

```js
function success(pos) {
  var coordinates = pos.coords;
  console.log(
    `Your location is: ${coordinates.latitude}} ${coordinates.longitude}`
  );
}

function error(error) {
  console.warn(`Error: ${error.message}`);
}

if ("permissions" in navigator) {
  navigator.permissions.query({
    name: "geolocation"
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.state === "granted") {
      console.log("granted");
    } else if (result.state === "denied") {
      console.log("denial");
    } else {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {
        timeout: 4000,
        maximumAge: 0
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**Note** this won't work in the snippet iframe so here's a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-cdn-zbevpj?file=/src/index.js) you can open in Safari in iOs to test. You should see the following prompt if you have location services for safari enabled:

[image]

Comment: the confusion from my own testing is that the permissions status never changes to `granted` in Safari even though it has been granted and doesn't prompt for the location anymore. it may just be a bug in Safari but curious of any insights

Comment: I'm also having this problem, it seems to be intentional but I don't know why?? Once again Apple decides they're special and don't need to follow the rules

Comment: Same problem on my end and this screws a whole flow of "permission" I'm building. You basically can't make a difference between someone who granted the permission or not, this is completely stupid from Apple.